# Mean vector and covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, covariance, means

I am given a home work for one subject, but my probability theory course is just started, so I dont have enough information. Could someone help me with that?
Given:
$$\begin{equation}
  p_\underline x(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \frac1\pi, & \text{if}\ x^2_1+x^2_2 < 1 \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}  $$
Find the mean and covariance matrix of the random vector of:
$$ \underline y=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\underline x + \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ \end{bmatrix}
 $$
Marginal distribution, mean and variance is already determined.
Help me please with doing mean and covariance matrix. If this will be explained and possibly given a link to some resource it would be quite helpful for me.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: not a complete solution, since you've already done most of the work, given what you've stated. Write

$$\underline{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{bmatrix}, \underline{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
Then we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 - x_2 + 2\\
2x_2+3
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
So, what this problem boils down to is finding the mean and covariance matrix of 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 - x_2 + 2\\
2x_2+3
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
The expected value is simply
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 - x_2 + 2\\
2x_2+3
\end{bmatrix} \right] = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[x_1 - x_2 + 2]\\
\mathbb{E}[2x_2+3]
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the covariance matrix is
$$\text{Cov}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 - x_2 + 2\\
2x_2+3
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
\text{Cov}\left(x_1 - x_2 + 2, x_1 - x_2 + 2\right) & \text{Cov}\left(x_1 - x_2 + 2, 2x_2+3\right) \\
\text{Cov}\left(2x_2+3, x_1 - x_2 + 2\right) & \text{Cov}\left(2x_2+3, 2x_2+3\right)
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
I will let you handle it from here.

Comment: Thank you for your help